# Fixed Position Resizing issues Overcome?

Tags: css

I want the logo to be perfectly in the top middle when the pic is fully extended, and I don't want it to display at all when I resize. I want it to scroll with the container so I can't avoid fixed position. You know a code I can use? Maybe a media cose? This is the way I edited do far, but results aren't those I hoped:

```
#logo { 
    top:20px; 
    left:50%; 
    margin-left:-177.6px; 
    width:355.2px; 
    height:148.8px; 
    position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need `margin-left` if you are using `left` to position it. Try using a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 1400px) {
    #logo {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

That's the gist of it.

Comment: You can use `transform: translateX(-50%);` and remove the `margin-left` like suggested above.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! This is what I was looking for in a way. The concept is exactly this one, but is there a way to keep it displayed? If I put margin-left off the element won't be in the middle of the top as I've just tried.